# Toggle true/false through radio buttons in AngularJS (inside of ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs

Hej, I've got an "almost" working fiddle. I have a list of items and I want to change their value if their radiobutton is selected. Here's the code:

CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyvQoP

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="food in foodList">
    <span>{{food.name}}</span>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="food.selected" name="radiofood" ng-value="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller("myController", myController)

function myController($scope) {
  $scope.foodList = [
    {
      name: 'banana',
      selected: 'false'
    },
    {
      name: 'orange',
      selected: 'false'
    },
    {
      name: 'apple',
      selected: 'false'
    }
  ]
}
```

**The problem:**
A radiobutton once clicked, changes it's value to **true** but clicking another one does not change the previous one to **false**. So if you click each one of them, one by one, all of them will be true. I only want one to have the true value.

Thanks

**--- Edit 2016-03-31 ---**
I was looking for a solution without writing a custom fuction but it turns out this can't be done. I've marked @Ankit Pundhir answer as the best one but it wasn't exaclty what i was aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add method to controller file:

```
$scope.selectFood = function(selectedFood){
    angular.forEach($scope.foodList,function(food){
        if(food != selectedFood){
            food.selected = false;
        }
    })
};
```

and add `ng-change="selectFood(food)"` to radio button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is writing a custom fuction the only way? Can't angular handle it through some ng-value/model thing?

Comment: If you want angular to handle it, you must share the same model for the options.

Comment: @tpsilva this will not update individual food selection. Also track on food item will get lost.

Comment: I think till now this is the solution, I will share some other solution as soon as i get it.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to add ng-change event on the input and then write a function which takes selectedFood as param and do the following:

1. Iterates through foodList and changes every value to false
2. Toggle status of selectedFood (if true set false end vice versa)

Something like this:

```
$scope.toggleParam = function(selectedFood){
    loopThroughAndSetToFalse();
    findAndSetReverseValue(selectedFood);
}
function loopThroughAndSetToFalse(){
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.foodList.length; i++){
    $scope.foodList[i].selected = false;
  }
}
function findAndSetReverseValue(selectedFood){
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.foodList.length; i++){
    if($scope.foodList[i].name === selectedFood.name){
        $scope.foodList[i].selected = !(selectedFood.selected);
    }
  }
}
```

And your html now will look like this:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="food in foodList">
   <span>{{food.name}}</span>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="food.selected" name="radiofood" ng-change="toggleParam(food)"  ng-value="true">
  </div>
  <br><br>
  {{foodList[0]}}<br>
  {{foodList[1]}}<br>
  {{foodList[2]}}
</div>
```

Comment: can you define `loopThroughAndSetToFalse` and `findAndSetReverseValue` ? Also what else i did?

Comment: I edit my post and defined two methods, also changed some code parts

Comment: Your code having a complexity of 2O(n) I think this can be done only in single loop. Also your code may get failed if 2 foods having same name with difference in other properties.  It will be better if you only compare there reference. eg `$scope.foodList[i] === selectedFood` .

Comment: "Also your code may get failed if 2 foods having same name with difference in other properties" - you are right, but this case is single selection and therefore it has to have different values. "Your code having a complexity of 2O(n)" - you are right your solution is clearly better, I simply tried to give an easy to understand solution.